# How to get contacts address from Contacts.SearchAsync results?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I am binding a listbox with contacts address using following xaml code

```
<ListBox Name="ContactResultsDataLINQ" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="200" Margin="24,0,0,0" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Addresses[0].PhysicalAddress.AddressLine1, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, this only binds AddressLine1...what i want it complete address = AddressLine1 + AddressLine2 + City

Now how do i append this additional properties via xaml code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use two `TextBlock` elements, or combine it in a single, using `Run` elements.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Addresses[0].PhysicalAddress.AddressLine1, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Run Text=" " />
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Addresses[0].PhysicalAddress.AddressLine2, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Run Text=" " />
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Addresses[0].PhysicalAddress.City, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```