# How to retrieve contact addresses in a string in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Windows Phone contacts' details can be bind in UI like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945374/how-to-get-contacts-address-from-contacts-searchasync-results) and other details like emails, phone nos etc can also be retrieved by Enumerating Contact Data Results like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785598/how-to-read-all-email-addresses-phone-numbers-etc-stored-in-a-windows-phone-con) but I AM UNABLE TO USE ANY OF THESE TO GET "ADDRESSES" OF CONTACTS IN A STRING (the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785598/how-to-read-all-email-addresses-phone-numbers-etc-stored-in-a-windows-phone-con) link works great for all other properties but doesn't provide addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you have instance of your contact that you are looking for - contact and contactItem to put data:

```
Contact contact = App.con;
Dictionary<string,string> contactItem = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

You could find all addresses with:

```
//Addresses
i = 0;
IEnumerable<ContactAddress> ad = contact.Addresses;
foreach (ContactAddress item in ad)
{
   i++;
   contactItem.Add("Adress " + i + " - " + item.Kind + ": ", item.PhysicalAddress.AddressLine1 + " " + item.PhysicalAddress.City);
}
```